# AngularJS - Wait for Response from Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application with AngularJS that communicates with an ASP.NET Web Api Server.

In the angular client i have couple of services that communicate with the server through the $http core service.

The problem is that i can't return actual results from the http request but only a promise.

Lets say that i have a service that returns an array of tickets (some resource of my application) from the server:

```
myService.getAll = function () {

    var result = $http.get('/api/tickets').then(function (result) {

        if (result.status !== 200)
            return [];

        return result.data;

    }, function (err) {

        return [];

    }); 

};
```

What can i do if i want to explicitly return the data of the result (or an empty array on failure) from the service and not a promise?

Is there a way to wait for a response in Angular?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: *"What can i do if i want to explicitly return the data of the result (or an empty array on failure) from the service and not a promise?"* nothing, what you are asking for isn't possible. Returning the promise is the only option that makes sense.

Comment: "Is there a way to wait for a response in Angular?" Yes, through promises.

Comment: @KevinB what doesn't make sense in waiting for response? .net can do it, even javascript can do it if i use jquery, so why not Angular?

Comment: angular doesn't support synchronous ajax requests (which is a good thing, those are evil.)

Comment: @ZackTanner Let me restate it, can i make a synchronous request with $http?

Comment: You can however resort to using the xhr object manually, nothing prevents you from doing so, but don't forget to start the digest cycle when it completes. I strongly suggest against it.

Comment: @KevinB So you are saying that Angular lacks the ability to make synchronous http requests?
I just want my services to return simple objects like arrays and not promises...

Comment: Yes, it lacks that ability, which makes it a good library. it's hindering you from doing something that is actively harmful to your application. You can almost consider it a feature.

Comment: synchronous requests are depreciated and therefore not supported in Angular. DO NOT use them.

Comment: Arik why can't you save the data in the service then use $promise.then() and grab the data from the service once it gets the data? Do you need it to be synchronous(timing wise) or is your main issue actually getting the data and not the promise returned?

Comment: @IfTrue There is no specific reason why i need it to be synchronous, i actually prefer it to be asynchronous, but i just like the idea of returning simple objects like arrays from services instead of promises, but since everyone is so strongly against it, i think that i will stick to the norms and use promises.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well if you think about it if it is Asynchronous how could it return the data as an array before it gathers it :) You otherwise would be having to be listening to the connection the entire time and wait for the array to be populated which is a lot more work than just waiting for a success and grabbing the now populated array.

Comment: @IfTrue Yes, that was my idea, to wait for the response until it returned from the server, i prioritized the idea of returning arrays from my services over the disadvantages of calling the server asynchronously, but maybe it was wrong of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, what you are asking for isn't possible with angular.

You can get this functionality if you resort to instead using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, however, I strongly suggest against it because it will negatively impact your application.

Yes, it might make it easier for you to understand and write your code, however, it will negatively impact your end-users by locking the browser up while it is "waiting" for the synchronous request to finish. The user will be unable to do anything within their browser, including changing to other tabs, typing in inputs, clicking buttons, and even animated gifs wont animate. css animations won't run, etc. **To the end user, your application will look broken until the request finishes.**

To top all of that off, synchronous ajax requests have been deprecated in modern browsers, so it's likely they'll be gone completely in a couple of years (if not sooner,) meaning you'll either have to update your application to use asynchronous requests later, or just not support browsers that drop support for sync requests.

The best option is to embrace promises.

```
myService.getAll = function () {

    return $http.get('/api/tickets').then(function (result) {

        if (result.status !== 200)
            return [];

        return result.data;

    }, function (err) {

        return [];

    }); 

};
```

Comment: If you still want to know *why* you can't simply wait with javascript, this video might help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ Basically, javascript is single threaded, and it will not continue on to the next callback in the callback queue until the current callstack is done executing. this is why a synchronous request causes so many problems in javascript.

Comment: Note that the browser rendering tasks also pass through the callback queue, which is why the sync request also stops animated gifs, css animations, and general page view updates.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to wait fr the response, but you have to pass data to your controller by implementing callback function, for example you service looks like

```
    myService.getAll = function (callback) {

    var result = $http.get('/api/tickets').then(function (result) {

        if (result.status !== 200)
            return [];
       if(typeof(callback)=="function")
         {
           callback(result.data)
         }


    }, function (err) {

        return [];

    }); 

};
```